# Check to see if Android MediaRecorder is Recording

Tags: android, audio-recording, android-mediaplayer, android-mediarecorder

I've written some code for Android 2.2 that plays an audio file using the Android MediaPlayer. Without getting into the details of the code, I noticed that there exists a function called

```
isPlaying()
```

that allows you to check if an audio file is currently being played by the MediaPlayer. So, for example, when the following snippet of code runs

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sound playing is: " +
        mediaPlayer.isPlaying(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

it displays the following message

```
Sound playing is: true / false
```

depending on whether there's sound playing or not.

When I wrote some code to record sound from the microphone using the Android MediaRecorder, however, I noticed that there did *not* look like there exists a function called

```
isRecording()
```

that checks to see whether a recording is in progress.

So, I was wondering if the onus is on the programmer then to figure out if a recording is in progress by embedding some logic into their code - or if perhaps there indeed exists a way to do this (check if a recording is in progress) by using another in-built function offered by the Android API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't look like there is such a function after all. I think it makes sense to try to embed some logic in the code to do this cleanly.

Answer (score 4):

### Important

I found a nice workaround to handle this issue, and you can read the workaround right away, but I strongly suggest that you read the entire explanation first.

### The scenario

I was trying to find a way to figure out if the mediarecorder had started recording or not, I assumed that calling the `start()` method on the recorder after the `prepare()` method was enough, but it turns out, it isn't.

Before you get offended by what I just said, Let me explain the scenario...

I was building a simple audio recording app from scratch, no libraries, copy paste, all hardwork. So I knew exactly what each part of my code is doing. Or at least I thought I did.

Until I decided to try and break my application by clicking on the buttons to start and stop recording like I was playing a piano. And yes, my stop button wasn't even appearing until the mediarecorder's `start()` method was called.

So I was greeted with a crash and logcat welcomed me with

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: stop failed.
    at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)
```

along with

```
E/MediaRecorder(15709): stop failed: -1007
```

So I read online and found out that calling `stop()` right after `start()` on `MediaRecorder` causes this problem.

So the biggest question was, **how do I detect if it is now SAFE for me to enable the STOP button on my recorder?**

### The Workaround (Not at all perfect, but it works)

```kotlin
MediaRecorder.getMaxAmplitude() // The maximum absolute amplitude measured since the last call, or 0 when called for the first time
```

As you can see, the `MediaRecorder.getMaxAmplitude()` method or the `MediaRecorder.maxAmplitude` property return 0 when called for the first time and the amplitude after that.

So, instead of allowing the user to Stop the recording right after calling `MediaRecorder.start()` I am now waiting until the `MediaRecorder.maxAmplitude` value is greater than zero, at which point I can be sure that the **MediaRecorder is initialized, started, and recording, and is in a state where calling `stop()` is allowed.** You can accomplish this by using a **runnable that keeps checking until the amplitude is greater than 0**. I am already using a runnable for the timer, so I perform the check in that.

### Please Note

When **working on an emulator**, the value returned by `MediaRecorder.maxAmplitude` is always 0. So, you should use an Android Device to check if everything works as expected.

Now my buttons stay disabled for less than a second when I first start recording. But if I stop and start too quickly, they remain disabled for a bit longer, and I show a "**Please wait while the recording starts**" message for the user.

I hope this answer helps someone.

Regards!