# Video recording only works on my device but not on other devices

Tags: android, android-camera, android-video-player

I uploaded  my app to google play and I noticed that the video recording does not work on other devices ,  on my device work fine.
So I did a debug and I discovered that I get an error message "failed to the create directory", I realized that this is because the device no include SD card.
I moved my SD card to the other device and it seems that the camera starts to record but when I click STOP the app crashes.

my device android 4.0.3 LG OPTIMUS (work)

on HTC 4.0.3 (not work)

[i find this , this could be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833694/mediarecorder-stop-stop-failed-1007)

[here my project](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4MOMQw6TMrzZTVnQ1JfRjAwY1k/edit?usp=sharing)

[Which is based on Google's training](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#manifest)

main activity :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import android.media.CamcorderProfile;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Debug;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {



    private Button initBtn = null ; 
    private Button startBtn = null ;
    private Button stopBtn = null ;
    private Button playBtn = null ;
    private Button stopPlayBtn = null ;
    private TextView recordingMSG = null ;
    private VideoView videoView = null ;


    static String TAG = "MainActivity" ; 
    private String outputFileName ; 
    private Camera mCamera;  
    private SurfaceView mPreview;
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    private boolean isRecording = false;
    private FrameLayout preview = null ;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        initBtn =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.initBtn)  ; 
        startBtn =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.startBtn)  ;
        stopBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopBtn)  ;
        playBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playBtn)  ;
        stopPlayBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopPlayBtn)  ;
        recordingMSG = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.recordingMSG) ;



         if ( !checkCameraHardware(this)){
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "not recognize device camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //chack syntax 
         }

         //play button can not play in the begin 
         playBtn.setEnabled(false);



        Log.d(TAG,"end creat");

    }



    //if clicked on one of the button 
    public void ButtonTapped(View view){
        int id = view.getId();
        if (id == R.id.initBtn) {
            Log.d(TAG, "idan initialize button") ;
            initRecorder();
        } else if (id == R.id.startBtn) {
            beginRecording();
        } else if (id == R.id.stopBtn) {
            stopRecording();
        } else if (id == R.id.playBtn) {
            playRecording();
        } else if (id == R.id.stopPlayBtn) {
            stopPlayback();
        }}





    private void stopPlayback() {


    }



    private void playRecording() {      

     PuseAndRelease(); //try    
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, StartPlay.class);
     intent.putExtra("outputFileName",outputFileName);
     startActivity(intent);
     finish(); 


    StartAndContinuCamera(); //try


    }



    private void stopRecording() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



    private void beginRecording() {


        if (isRecording) {
            // stop recording and release camera
            mMediaRecorder.stop();  // stop the recording
            releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
            mCamera.lock();         // take camera access back from MediaRecorder

            // inform the user that recording has stopped
            //setCaptureButtonText("Capture");
            startBtn.setText("start");
            isRecording = false;
            playBtn.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            // initialize video camera
            if (prepareVideoRecorder()) {
                // Camera is available and unlocked, MediaRecorder is prepared,
                // now you can start recording
                mMediaRecorder.start();
                Log.d(TAG,"MEDIA RECORDER START");

                // inform the user that recording has started
                //setCaptureButtonText("Stop");
                startBtn.setText("stop");
                isRecording = true;
            } else {
                // prepare didn't work, release the camera
                releaseMediaRecorder();
                // inform user
            }
        }   



    }



    private void initRecorder() {


    }











    private boolean prepareVideoRecorder(){

        //mCamera = getCameraInstance();
         mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
        mCamera.unlock();
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);


        // Step 2: Set sources
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
        mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));




        // Step 4: Set output file
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());
        outputFileName = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString() ; 


        // Step 5: Set the preview output
        mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());

        // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
        try {
            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }







    /** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
    private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
          return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                  Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }








     @Override
        protected void onPause() {
         super.onPause();
         PuseAndRelease();
        }

        @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        StartAndContinuCamera();

    }




        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDestroy();



        }




        public void StartAndContinuCamera(){


            // Create an instance of Camera
            mCamera = getCameraInstance();
            Log.d(TAG,"camera on resume"+ " " + mCamera );  
            // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
            mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
            FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);  
            preview.addView(mPreview);

            Log.d(TAG,"camera on resume"+ " " + mCamera );  

        }
















        public void PuseAndRelease (){

            releaseMediaRecorder();       // if you are using MediaRecorder, release it first
            releaseCamera();  // release the camera immediately on pause event
            Log.d(TAG,"camera onpause" + mCamera );

        }










        private void releaseMediaRecorder(){
            if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
                mMediaRecorder.reset();   // clear recorder configuration
                mMediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
                Log.d(TAG,"release the recorder") ;
                mMediaRecorder = null;
                mCamera.lock();           // lock camera for later use
                Log.d(TAG," CAMERA lock") ;
            }
        }

        private void releaseCamera(){
            if (mCamera != null){
                mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);

                mPreview.getHolder().removeCallback((Callback) mPreview);//try
                mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications

                Log.d(TAG,"camera release");
                mCamera = null;
            }
        }








        /** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
        public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
            Camera c = null;
            try {
                c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
            }
            return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
        }







    private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
        Log.d(TAG,"test") ;
        if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
            // this device has a camera
            return true;
        } else {
            // no camera on this device
            return false;
        }
    }

















}
```

logcat :

```
   05-31 13:34:04.449: V/MediaRecorderJNI(19487): stop
05-31 13:34:04.449: V/MediaRecorderJNI(19487): getMediaRecorder E
05-31 13:34:04.499: V/MediaRecorderJNI(19487): JNIMediaRecorderListener::notify
05-31 13:34:04.499: V/MediaRecorderJNI(19487): notify msgType 0x65, ext1 0x100003E8
05-31 13:34:04.659: E/MediaRecorder(19487): stop failed: -1007
05-31 13:34:04.659: V/MediaRecorderJNI(19487): process_media_recorder_call
05-31 13:34:04.659: D/AndroidRuntime(19487): Shutting down VM
05-31 13:34:04.659: W/dalvikvm(19487): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40af7228)
05-31 13:34:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19487): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-31 13:34:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19487): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
05-31 13:34:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19487):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3071)
05-31 13:34:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19487):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3538)
05-31 13:34:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19487):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14330)
05-31 13:34:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19487):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:608)
05-31 13:34:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19487):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-31 13:34:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19487):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
05-31 13:34:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19487):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
05-31 13:34:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19487):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-31 13:34:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19487):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-31 13:34:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19487):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-31 13:34:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19487):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-31 13:34:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19487):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-31 13:34:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19487): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-31 13:34:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19487):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-31 13:34:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19487):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-31 13:34:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19487):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3066)
05-31 13:34:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19487):    ... 11 more
05-31 13:34:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19487): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: stop failed.
05-31 13:34:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19487):    at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)
05-31 13:34:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19487):    at com.example.your_voice.MainActivity.beginRecording(MainActivity.java:141)
05-31 13:34:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19487):    at com.example.your_voice.MainActivity.ButtonTapped(MainActivity.java:93)
05-31 13:34:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(19487):    ... 14 more
```

Comment: is it possible to get some error message from logcat?

Comment: sure java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Comment: it would be more useful to post the complete stacktrace to see in which lines the issue is...

Comment: I added the requested

Comment: it is a little bit confusing that your stopRecording() method is empty, but is called when you click stopButton..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must the preview size be same as camera profile
At CameraPreview.surfaceCreated change to this:

```
Log.d(TAG, "surfaceCreated camera id" + mCamera);

try {
    CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPreviewSize(profile.videoFrameWidth, profile.videoFrameHeight);
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
    mCamera.startPreview();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
}
```